# Template for Spring Boot error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, spring-security-oauth2

I have an OAuth 2.0 authorization server created using Spring Boot and the legacy @EnableAuthorizationServer. An extract of the security configuration can be found below:

```
http
    .requestMatchers()
        .mvcMatchers("/login", "/profile", "/oauth/authorize", "/.well-known/jwks.json")
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .mvcMatchers("/login", "/.well-known/jwks.json").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
```

Everything is working fine and now I'm creating Thymeleaf templates for error messages. Errors like 404 are shown with my custom page, using a file 404.html under resources/templates/error. There is a generic resources/templates/error.html for any unhandled exception.

For some reason, the template 401.html is not being rendered. Instead, Spring keeps returning the default response with the code 401 and the content below:

```
<oauth>
  <error_description>Full authentication is required to access this resource</error_description>
  <error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

Do you know if this can be changed and how? Just to be clear, I don't want to remove the error but to return a custom content.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You should tell Spring Security that you don't want authentication on your error page with something like this :

```
http.authorizeRequests().mvcMatchers("/your/error/page/url").permitAll();
```

Comment: Hi Fabien, thanks for the answer. However, that doesn't really help. First of all there is no such a thing as a URL for the error pages, they're not endpoints. Spring will generate, for e.g., a 404 or 401 response when appropriate, but not really redirect the user to another URL.